# How can I pass an attribute as a parameter with Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am a newbie with Angular 8.
I would like to pass an array of interfaces to a sort function, and I would like to pass interface attributes as parameters. 
For now I have tried this way:

```
sortBy<T, K keyof T>(field: K, arr: T[], mode: 'Asc' | 'Desc'): T[] {
    const res = arr.sort((x, y) => x[field].localCompare(y[field], undefined, { sesitivity: 'base' }));

    return mode === 'Asc'
      ? res
      : res.reverse();
}
```

But I am noticing that the editor (VSCode) is reporting to me some inaccuracies, in particular:
[image]
[image]
[image]


I can't decipher these comments. What should I do to optimize my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the K parameter:

```
sortBy<T>(field: keyOf T, arr: T[], mode: 'Asc' | 'Desc'): T[]
```

Comment: Now `Property 'localCompare' does not exist on type 'T[keyof T]'` and don't compile. While the rest is ok.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, field is typed as an object k, and ofc, you cannot use an object as index. If you wanna call a parameter, you have 2 options :

```
const x = object.param;
```

Or

```
const x = object['param'];
```

In your case, your param 'field' need to be a string, then you will be able to do:

```
x[field]
```

Comment: No error on VSCode, but an error in the console `ERROR TypeError: x[field].localCompare is not a function`, that compromises the functioning of the sorting.

Comment: It means, your x[field] object, doesn t have a function localCompare, you tried to console.log the variable ?

Comment: My fault, I forgot an _e_ :)